# Выполнить запрос на сумму по отдельным полям

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал три таблицы, из которых хочу получить результат на:

Имя клиента, его адрес и СУММА ВСЕХ ЕГО ПОКУПОК. Тут была бы хороша сортировка по убыванию.

Не хватает опыта в этой сфере, какие могут быть идеи?

Comment: join всех  трех таблиц, group by по клиенту и sum(summ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу прощения за оформление - зашёл с телефона. Здесь нужен перекрестный запрос с группировкой по клиенту (на случай, если попадутся полные тезки, сделаем группировку ещё и по адресу:

```
SELECT 
   c.name as ClientName, 
   c.address as ClientAddress,
    SUM(b.summ) as Summ
   FROM table1 a
   INNER JOIN Clients c ON a.Clients_id = c.Id
   INNER JOIN Buy b on a.buy_id = b.id
Group by ClientName, ClientAddress
```